# Starship theme symbols not showing up correct in VSCode terminal

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, zsh, oh-my-zsh

Symbol shows as such in
[VSCode terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jy3MT.png) when it is supposed to appear like this in the [macOS terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1Or1.png). I have already set the correct terminal font in VSCode.

Answer (score 13):

You can change the terminal font setting for VS Code and use a *Nerd Font* as suggested in Starship's [documentation](https://starship.rs/faq/#why-don-t-i-see-a-glyph-symbol-in-my-prompt). To do that either go to the settings and search for `Terminal Font` and update the value or you can add this to your `settings.json`.

```json
"terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "'FiraMono Nerd Font Mono'",
```

You can download the fonts [here](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads). Make sure you are writing the correct name. This worked for me in fedora zsh shell. Should work for macOS as well.

[image: vscode terminal]

Comment: It worked for me on Ubuntu 22.04, adding the line "terminal.integrated.fontFamily": "Monospace, 'AurulentSansMono Nerd Font Mono'".

Comment: it doesnot work for me on macos 12.6

Comment: @LuísAssunção didnt work for me. 22.04

Comment: This should be "FiraCode Nerd Font Mono" (typo above?).

Comment: @GabeSumner Both are valid fonts: https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads, I was using the FiraMono one.